# No module named 'dns' python

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a discord bot experience system using mysql. I got the database all set up but when I tried to import it into the script I kept getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 119, in <module>
    vspd.debug(filename, port_num, debug_id, debug_options, run_as)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\debugger.py", line 39, in debug
    run()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\Packages\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 312, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ikee1\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer\Programing\Python Code\Chirp Bot\Chirp Bot\Chirp Bot\Chirp_Bot.py", line 6, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import dns.resolver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've tried importing dnspython with the Microsoft command prompt and I've tried downloading it from the website and the github. I also downloaded node.js (and everything the tutorial i'm following told me to). Here is my python code (I *blanked* out the "sensitive" info):

```
import os
import discord
import mysql.connector
from discord.ext import commands


client = discord.Client()

token = *blank*
Guild = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')


bot_prefix = "C"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='C')


chirpDataBase =  mysql.connector.connect(host = *blank*, user = *blank*, passwd = *blank*, database = "ChirpBotUserLevels", auth_plugin = "mysql_native_password")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')




client.run(token)
```

I'm not sure how to fix it and any help would be appreciated (sorry if I got any programming terms wrong I'm still pretty new to it) thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? Which versions of the packages are you using, for example?

Comment: Yes, I am using visual studios 2019, I believe it is fully updated and I'm using the latest version of mysql also.